# How do I solve Schroedinger's equation for sterile neutrinos?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

When reading [Light singlet neutrinos and the primordial nucleosynthesis](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/037026939090054A?token=28A1E0945485050E17486E69760619333676ED803B036D85BAA1AB92BE10637F3D017FDE04EEF9C8CFE71275E4F35722) the following equation is given:

$$\tag{5} i \frac{\partial}{\partial t } \begin{pmatrix} c_e (t) \\ c_x (t) \end{pmatrix}= \frac{\Delta _m }{2}\begin{pmatrix} cos2\theta_m & sin2\theta_m \\ sin2\theta_m & cos 2\theta_m\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_e (t) \\ c_x (t) \end{pmatrix}$$

Given the wave function below:

$$\nu(t) = c_e (t) \nu_e + c_x (t) \nu_x$$

in here $\nu_x$ represents sterile neutrinos and $\nu_e$ represents electron-neutrinos.

The equation above can be solved as to give the probability to find such wavefunction in the state $\nu_x$ at the time $t$:

$$P_{\nu_e \to \nu_x} (t)  = |c_x (t) |^2 = sin^2 2\theta_m  sin^2 \left( \frac{1}{2} \Delta_m t\right) \tag{7}$$

**How is (5) solved to give us (7)? How does the $c_e$ term vanish in this integration?**

**The variable integrated in this case is time, if so, then how does one integrate the $c_e(t)$ and $c_x(t)$ terms that depend on the variable?**

---

My take on it:

$$i \frac{\partial}{ \partial t} c_x = \frac{\Delta m}{2} (sin 2\theta c_e + cos2\theta c_x)$$

$$i \frac{\partial}{ \partial t} c_e = \frac{\Delta m}{2} (cos 2\theta c_e + sin 2\theta c_x)$$

I manipulated the top equation to obtain $c_x $in terms of $c_e $. And rewrote it as :

$$c_e = \frac{2i}{\Delta m sin2 \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} c_x - tan^{-1} 2\theta c_x$$

Tried substituting this back into the bottom equation but I didn't know how to differentiate it.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by integration? Do you mean solving the differential equation?
2. What are your initial conditions? (I suspect the model starts off with only electron neutrinos. Does it?)

Comment: Please note that  in the title the Shrodinger equations is irrelevant, The Schrodnger equations is not used in QFT as it is no relativistic.  The neutrinos  in additions are fermions and have be represented by solutions of the Dirac equation

Comment: So how should I reword the question?

Comment: I intend to get to the probability equation given, and the model starts off with only electron neutrinos at time $t=0$ as you stated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Right, that's a pretty standard neutrino oscillation problem. Do you know how to solve two coupled first-order differential equations?

Comment: I have tried doing as you just said, simultaneously, by using the two equations provided but I must be going wrong somewhere as I don't seem to get a solution for $c_x$

Comment: Good. I would suggest that you modify the question to include what you have got so far, so that people can help you by knowing where exactly it is that you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way to solve two simultaneous coupled differential equations. (To be honest, I'm not completely sure how exactly you managed to get what you say you did!) I won't solve the whole problem, but I'll give you a couple of pointers of how to get to the solution.

The point is that rate of change of the variables $c_x$ depends not only on the value of $c_x$, but also of $c_e$, and so you can't simply "integrate" the left and right hand sides to get anything meaningful. The best thing to do is to find some *combination* of $c_x$ and $c_e$ such that this pair of coupled equations reduces to two uncoupled differential equations, which you can *then* integrate. (This is very similar to how the [two-masses-three-springs](http://www.physics.hmc.edu/%7Esaeta/courses/p111/uploads/Y2013/chap13.pdf) problems are solved.)

The easiest way to solve such equations is using matrices, but it isn't clear to me how much linear algebra you know, and so I'm going to try an approach using only differential equations, but it requires a little bit of mathematical intuition to decouple the equations.

The equations in question that you have are

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}c_e(t) &= -\frac{i \Delta}{2} \Bigg( \cos(2\theta)\,\, c_e(t) + \sin(2\theta)\,\, c_x(t)\Bigg)\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}c_x(t) &= -\frac{i \Delta}{2} \Bigg( -\sin(2\theta)\,\, c_e(t) + \cos(2\theta)\,\, c_x(t)\Bigg)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

where, since the coefficients depend only on time, I have replaced the partial derivative with a total derivative, and I've ignored all the $m$s to make it easier to write. Also, you had an error in your matrix: in the second row, it should be $-\sin(2\theta)$.

Now, the trick is to realise that if you multiply the second equation by $i$ and you add and subtract the equations, you can show that (I'll leave it as an exercise):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} \Big( c_e(t) + i\, c_x (t) \Big) &= -\frac{i \Delta}{2} e^{- i 2\theta} \Big(c_e(t) + i\, c_x(t)\Big)\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\Big( c_e(t) - i\, c_x (t) \Big)  &= -\frac{i \Delta}{2} e^{i 2\theta} \Big(c_e(t) -i\, c_x(t)\Big)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

If we define two new variables $c_1 = c_e(t) + i\, c_x (t)$ and $c_2 = c_e(t) - i\, c_x (t)$, our equations magically become decoupled!

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} c_1(t) &= -\frac{i \Delta}{2} e^{- i 2\theta} c_1(t)\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} c_2(t)  &= -\frac{i \Delta}{2} e^{i 2\theta} c_2(t)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

You can now solve these equations for $c_1(t)$ and $c_2(t)$, and from there you can find $c_e(t)$ and $c_x(t)$.

The state of the system at any time $t$ is given by $\nu(t) = \begin{pmatrix}c_e(t)\\c_x(t)\end{pmatrix}$, where the upstairs element is the probability (amplitude) of finding an electron-neutrino and the downstairs element is the probability (amplitude) of finding a "sterile" neutrino. In the problem, you are given that the state originally starts off as an electron neutrino, and so $c_e = 1, c_x = 0$ (which are the initial conditions you will need when you solve the above differential equations). However, at some later time, $c_e(t) \neq 1$ and $c_x(t) \neq 0$, meaning that there is a probability that a measurement will result in a neutrino that *isn't* an electron-neutrino.

The probability of finding the neutrino as a "sterile" neutrino at some later time is $|c_x(t)|^2$, and so after you find the value of $c_x(t)$, then the probability that you get a "sterile" neutrino at some time $t$, given that you started with an electron neutrino at $t=0$, denoted by $P_{\nu_e \to \nu_x}(t)$, is

$$P_{\nu_e \to \nu_x}(t)=|c_x(t)|^2.$$

---

**EDIT:**

Ok this is odd. I don't think my method is wrong, but I don't seem to be able to reproduce the result in Equation (7) given in the paper, and I don't really know why. Looking online, Equation 3.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.11389.pdf), seems to use a different matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}-\cos{2\theta}&\sin{2\theta}\\ \sin{2\theta}&\cos{2\theta}\end{pmatrix},$$
and using this I get the expected result for the probability. I'm not sure why this is happening. Perhaps the paper you've linked messed up their matrix, or perhaps there's something going on here that's above my pay-grade... I'd appreciate it if anyone had any insights.